# What is wrong with this trigger syntax? I'm trying to convert a sqlite database to mySQL

Tags: mysql, syntax, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER JobPositionFKDelete
    AFTER DELETE ON darkrp_position
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN OLD.type = `T`
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM darkrp_jobspawn
               WHERE darkrp_jobspawn.id = OLD.id;
    END;
```

Comment: What error do you get? I see that `T` is incorrectly quoted. A string literal should have single quotes as `'T'` not backticks as `\`T\``

Comment: Also the `WHEN` syntax looks quite wrong there. Probably you mean to use `IF OLD.type = 'T' THEN....END IF`